# About Selecting Front Vertices？

Tags: scripting

blender 3.4.1

I haven't found a particularly good way, currently relying on select_box.

## What I want is all visible vertices facing the screen

I couldn't find any api to do this directly, I added a picture to illustrate

## In the figure are two independent squares

**This is the vertex I want**

[image]

**other perspective**

[image]

**more realistic scenario**

[image]

```py
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector
import numpy as np

def get_verts_in_view(context):
    view3dArea = context.area
    view3dRegion = context.region
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT') 
    vertIdxs = {}
    with context.temp_override(area=view3dArea, region=view3dRegion):
        bpy.ops.view3d.select_box(
            xmin=0,xmax=view3dArea.width,
            ymin=0,ymax=view3dArea.height,
            mode='ADD')
        objects = [obj for obj in context.scene.objects if obj.type == 'MESH' 
                and obj.select_get()]
        
        for obj in objects:
            bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT') 
            context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
            
     # bmesh is just to restore the previous selection state, and it is not used for any operation
            bm = bmesh.new()   
            bm.from_mesh(obj.data)
            bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
            bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type="VERT")
            
            bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action = 'DESELECT')
            bpy.ops.view3d.select_box(
                xmin=0,xmax=view3dArea.width,
                ymin=0,ymax=view3dArea.height,
                mode='ADD')
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
            vertIdxs[obj.name] = [vert.index for vert in obj.data.vertices if vert.select]

            
            bm.to_mesh(obj.data)
            bm.free()
            
    return vertIdxs
```

This is the most basic code, I used bmesh to store the previous selection state.

The problem is that I don't have much experience, is it reliable for me to do this? Or are there any other risks? Welcome to suggest a better solution.

Thanks

Comment: When you say front vertices, do you mean like front facing? or front meaning like, only in the negative Y area of the object? Also, I don't really understand why you're even including bmesh in this implementation because as far as I can tell you aren't using it at all. I would say, however, that trying to figure out a way to achieve this via bmesh is going to be vastly superior than this method. Using bpy.ops and trying to override contexts and what not is always the worse option. Only to be used as a last resort.

Comment: a numpy solution would be even better than bmesh

Comment: @Jakemoyo What I want is all visible vertices facing the screen, I couldn't find any api to do this directly, I added a picture to illustrate

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady bmesh is just to restore the previous selection state, and it is not used for any operation

Comment: @Jakemoyo I can't find a more reliable way to achieve this

Comment: Why is this vertex selected? https://i.imgur.com/BU6a4w5.png It's behind the bigger cube's front face. You still consider it visible? Then why so many front verts of the Suzanne are not selected?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady As mentioned earlier, they are two separate objects, this is why I didn't edit all objects at once

Comment: @zeronofreya I would consider getting the 3D View camera location as a vector, then using each vertex position as the start point for a ray cast, either by using context.scene.ray_cast or converting your object into a mathutils.bvhtree.BVHTree and then using the ray_cast method of that object. It's not a simple two-line solution, but I think it would be more reliable ultimately once you figure it out. I tried writing my own version of this to see if I could come up with a full answer, but didn't have time to get a working solution. But that seems like the way to go IMO.

Comment: Here is the code of what I managed to get working. I got it to where it selects most of the front facing verts but doesn't get the ones that are on the perimeter of what should be selected. A little more work should get it there but it's not finished enough to actually post as an answer. https://pastebin.com/5qvAiRDi

Comment: @Jakemoyo Thanks, I tried your script, but the vertices on the back are also selected, and the vertices on the edge are not selected. Looking forward to your perfect script, I will also learn bvhtree, thank you very much